# modifying a dataframe by adding additional if statement column

Tags: pandas, if-statement

Modifying a data frame by adding an additional column with if statement. 
I created  5 lists namely: East_Asia, Central_Asia,Central_America,South_America, Europe_East & Europe_West. And I wanted to add a conditional column based on existing column. i.e if japan in Central_East, then the japan row in the adding column should contain Central East, so on.

```
df['native_region'] =df["native_country"].apply(lambda x: "Asia-East" if x in 'Asia_East' 
                                               "Central-Asia" elif x in "Central_Asia"
                                                "South-America" elif x in "South_America"
                                                "Europe-West" elif x in "Europe_West"
                                                "Europe-East" elif x in "Europe_East"
                                                "United-States" elif x in " 
United-States" 
else "Outlying-US"
                                                 )
```

File "", line 2
    "Central-Asia" elif x in "Central_Asia"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your statement `x in "Asia_East"` probably caused the error because it is a string you are comparing. Remove the quotes accordingly and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think you're taking the problem the wrong way around.

What you seem to be doing there is just to replace '_' by '-', which you can do with the following line:
`df['native_region'] = df.native_country.str.replace('_', '-')`

And then, in my experience, it's more understandable to work like that :

```py
known_countries = ['Asia-East', 'Central-Asia', 'South-America', ...]
is_known = df['native_country'].isin(known_countries )
df.native_region[~known_countries] = 'Outlying-US'
```

This could work also if you worked with countries like :

```py
east_asia_countries = ['Japan', 'China', 'Korea']
isin_east_asia = df['native_country'].isin(east_asia_countries)
df.native_region[known_countries] = 'East-Asia'
```